# Not able to query an item with row key set as a GUID?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

My azure storage table's Row key is set as a GUID. Am not able to query the entity for some specific GUID's or it could be happening randomly. But for some GUID's however number of queries i make, it doesnt return the entity but i can clearly see the record in the table. I have no clue why thats happening. Could it be because am using different data service contexts for creating the entity and fetching the entity using the GUID. Below is the simple code snippet.

```
TableStorageServiceContext<PersistedAudioRecord> audioRecordServiceContext;
audioRecordServiceContext = new TableStorageServiceContext<PersistedAudioRecord>(TableNames.AudioRecord, cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.ToString(), cloudStorageAccount.Credentials) { IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true };

return audioRecordServiceContext.QueryableEntities.Where(b => b.RowKey == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have been banging my head about this issue, any ideas or suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're querying using just `RowKey`. This may result in full table scan and table service will only return a maximum of 1000 entities / request. If the table service encounters a `Partition Boundary`, it may return 0 entities. Can you please check when you don't get the data, you're getting a continuation token? You can check that using a tool like `Fiddler`.

Comment: Isnt fiddler for making HTTP requests? How can i make table queries in it?

Comment: And ya my table has more than 1000 entities pertaining to a single PartitionKey, So I can never make queries with just the RowKey? I would always need PartitionKey as well?

Comment: Regarding Fiddler, you just track the request/response with that. Regarding your 2nd comment - yes, you must use PartitionKey in your query to avoid table scans.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue.

Comment: I am facing another issue. Consider my scenario. I have about 200 partitions and each partition has about 1000 rowkeys(entities) or even more. So when i am making any query fetching records of a partition which is albhabetically last(starting with "z"), it doesnt return any results. Any idea how i can tackle this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467181/querying-on-azure-table-storage-doesnt-work-beyond-a-certain-number-of-entities