# Querying on Azure table storage doesnt work beyond a certain number of entities?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Consider my scenario. I have about 200 partitions and each partition has about 1000 rowkeys(entities) or even more. So when i am making any query fetching records of a partition which is albhabetically last(starting with "z"), it doesnt return any results.

Below is a sample query -

```
audioRecordServiceContext.QueryableEntities
                         .Where(p => p.PartitionKey == channel && 
                                     p.IsDedication == true && 
                                     p.IsBroadcast == true && 
                                     p.BroadcastTime >= time && 
                                     p.BroadcastTime < time.AddHours(1))
                         .ToList();
```

When i pass a channel starting with initial alphabets it returns entities properly but when I give a channel starting with probabaly "Z", it doesnt return any entities.

Any idea how i can tackle this issue?

EDIT:

Query string

```
http://sampleservice/devstoreaccount1/AudioRecord()?$filter=Username eq 'username'
```

Fiddler response for the query

```
**HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8
Server: Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 06dff157-f693-49a6-ade7-b7165a4d3dfb
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey: 1!16!QWZnaGFuaXN0YW4-
x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey: 1!48!YTZiOGQxZmYtYjNkYy00NDEyLTk2YmItZTViNmUyMWNhYzJi
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 12:19:03 GMT**
```

Comment: do you care about `case-sensitivity`?

Comment: "channel" that am comparing is exactly cased to what is there in the table so that shouldnt be a problem? I was told azure table storage can query only 1000 entities/request so am thinking those 1000 entities get over within in the initial partitions itself? Could that be an issue?

Comment: The 1000-entity limit isn't a factor, since you're providing query criteria including the partition. Have you tried checking the data using a tool like https://zud.io/ ?

Comment: When you execute the query, run Fiddler as well so that you can see exactly what is sent over the wire. You can see if the response contains `x-ms-NextPartitionKey` and `x-ms-NextRowKey` headers. It would be helpful, if you can post the actual request sent to the storage service (I'm more interested in seeing the query string part).

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that you are getting continuation tokens telling you to follow the chain of data. Continuation tokens can appear even if no entities are returned; that's what Gaurav is hinting to. The ExecuteAll and ExecuteAllWithRetries methods deal with continuation tokens automatically. See smark's blog for what happened to him... ;) http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-tables-expect-continuation-tokens-seriously

Comment: @HerveRoggero Apologies for the late reply. I have been looking at how to deal with the continuation tokens but I cant seem to find ExecuteAll method anywhere on the storage client library. has it been changed? I would really appreciate if anyone can share some code for handling continuation tokens.

Comment: @GauravMantri Hey! Have you used the continuation tokens lately? I havent been able to find ExecuteAll method in any storage client libraries. I have been stuck on this issue for days, I would really appreciate if you could throw some light on how i can handle continuation tokens. Preferably some latest sample code. Thanks

Comment: Which version of storage client library are you using? Also please share the Fiddler trace as I asked above.

Comment: Am using version 1.7 and i have added the fiddler trace.

Comment: @GauravMantri have added the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample code that fetches as many entities as needed based on the query being passed; in my environment this returns over 10,000 entities and it handles the continuation tokens automatically. I am not 100% sure of the SDK version this is using, but it *should* work with 1.7. The magic here is performed by the AsTableServiceQuery, which is an extension method provided by the SDK that performs both the pagination, and automatic retries.

The _tableName variable contains the name of my table.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

            var partitionQuery =
                (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<MyData1>(_tableName)
                 where e.PartitionKey.CompareTo("15") >= 0 && e.PartitionKey.CompareTo("39") <= 0
                 select new MyData1()
                 {
                     PartitionKey = e.PartitionKey,
                     RowKey = e.RowKey,
                     Timestamp = e.Timestamp,
                     Message = e.Message,
                     Level = e.Level,
                     Severity = e.Severity
                 }
                 ).AsTableServiceQuery();

            return partitionQuery.ToList<MyData1>();
```

The above code depends on a class called MyData1, defined as such:

```
public class MyData1 : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps...